# Where's the Skype Client spellchecking dictionary on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, dictionary

When typing in the Skype Client for Linux / Ubuntu, the spell checker makes a lot of mistakes.  Being based on Electron, it should allow adding words to the dictionary in the same way that Chromium does.  However upon right-clicking a words, no context menu to add the word appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *Skype for Linux* client delivered by `snap` keeps its custom dictionary at `/home/sid/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/Custom Dictionary.txt` however this file does not exist by default.

If you have *google-chrome* installed, this will pre-populate it with your existing custom dictionary words:

```
$ ln -s ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Custom\ Dictionary.txt ~/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/
```

If instead you are using *chromium-browser*, use this instead:

```
$ ln -s ~/.config/chromium/Default/Custom\ Dictionary.txt ~/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/
```

After this, each time you add a new word to the dictionary in your browser, it will appear after the next time you restart the *Skype* client.

It's better than nothing!